# Where can I find the exact semantics of Windows ACLs

Tags: windows, security, permissions, acl

Is there any place where I can find out an exact description of the Windows access control semantics, similar in detail to the `acl(5)` man page on Linux.  i.e. an algorithm that explains exactly how Windows decides to deny or grant access, given the ACL of the object and anything it inherits from.

Google suggests
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374872.aspx, but I am looking for much more precision.

realted questions: [How do Windows NT ACLs work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128068/how-do-windows-nt-acls-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[How AccessCheck works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446683%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) spells it out.

Comment: And see also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374924.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379298.aspx for stuff about inheritence.

Comment: ACE inheritance affects how the ACL for a new object is established, but the algorithm for how Windows decides whether to grant access or not doesn't care about inheritance. It works with the ACEs in the ACL regardless of their source.

Comment: Yep, I see that now that I read the page you pointed out.  But I also wanted to know about inheritence, which is why I added the extra links.